# personalized calender for each user in drupal 7 with Event Calender Module

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-views

Trying to have personalized calender for each user in **drupal 7** with **Event Calender Module.**

I have content type "**Channel**"."**User A**" create a content "**Channel A**" which content type is "**Channel**"
Meanwhile user A has access to the "Event Calender" and he created event called "**Event A**"

when the content "**Channel A**" is opened Even calender block is displaying  all events, but i need to filter it by the author who created the Channel & his events in Event Calender.

i tried using views to clone the block of Event Calender but i failed to filter the events based on the above logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each views that you need to be filtered by Current user id you have to add a **Contextual Fllter** of "**Content: Author uid**" and get the author id from node.

[image: Author id - Contextual filter]